# Set value from database onto textfield

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:BankSystem");
        select = "Select Name From MalaysiaWithdraw where AccountNo = ?;";
        stmtSelect = conn.createStatement();
        stmtUpdate = conn.createStatement();
        pstmtSelect = conn.prepareStatement(select);

        //get value from textField and pass it into prepareStatement
        String accNo = accNumber.getText();
        pstmtSelect.setString(1, accNo);
        rsSelect = pstmtSelect.executeQuery();
```

how can I get the Name from database and set it onto a textfield, let say the textfield is nameText.

Comment: Have checked with Javadoc? its pretty self explanatory. else try to elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

*how can I get the Name from database and set it onto a textfield, let say the textfield is nameText.* for this use ResultSet like this way

```
String Databasename;
while(rsSelect.next())
{

Databasename=rsSelect.getString("Name");
}
// your code for setting in the textfield
```

`Databasename` will have the `Name` from the Database.Now use this to set in the textfield

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the query only has one result, which is a name (select = "Select Name ...").

```
 rsSelect = pstmtSelect.executeQuery();

 String name;
 while (rsSelect.next()){
     name = rsSelect.getString(1);  // or getString("Name");  Name being the column name
 }

 textFieed.setText(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that text field name is "textFieldName"

```
Resultset rsSelect = pstmtSelect.executeQuery();

String name=null;

while(rs.next()) {
   name = rs.getString("Name");
}

if(name!=null){
   textFieldName.setText(name);
}
```